# Firebird on Mac OS X on a different port

Tags: macos, firebird, macos-sierra, firebird2.5

Installed on Mac OS X Sierra Firebird 2.5.7 version. The default port 3050 and connects to the database normally.

The challenge is to Firebird worked not a standard port. The file `firebird.conf` added a line to the desired port `RemoteServicePort = 12345`. reboot.

BUT: Firebird both worked with port 3050 and works, and a new port 12345 - does not take.

Tried the same steps in other operating systems (Windows and Linux) normally takes a new port.

Comment: I believe that Firebird on the Mac uses xinetd or something like that, so you'd need to change the port in that configuration. But I'm just guessing. You might want to consider asking this on the firebird-support mailinglist.

Answer (score 1):

Mistakenly put the Classic architecture, it is necessary to put SuperServer and it will work